# Why my sphere is compress at the end

Tags: animation

[image] Im making a simple animation a file attached. At the start its good sphere but as it start revolving the sphere is getting compress. Whats the reason and where im getting wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be that you scaled the curve after setting the constraint.

select the curve and hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> and apply scale...

it should be fixed. Screenshots will follow if needed...

The answer is already accepted, but since I already have done screenshots, here they are, showing the problem and the solution... may help others understand.

first you set the follow path animation:

[image]

then you Z-scale  the path and happens this

[image]

but you can select the path, and apply the Z-scale

[image]

so you get the correct ball shape, no more deformed...

[image]

**edit**

screenshots showing curve frames count for the same curve Z-scaled (applied)

72 frames for both curves:

[image]

the second curve has frames doubled now...

[image]

Comment: thanks for giving the reference image. One more question as my sphere is going to faster how to control the speed and drop down to slow

Comment: I think the ball is reaching the curve end in the same time as before. If the curve has been scaled (and applied), the speed could be faster, since the time is the same, but the path is longer... you can change the curve "path animation" frames setting to change the speed... see two more screenshots...